# Find : $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Find :

$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}$$

My attempt : i don't know is correct or no!
I use this rule :

$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(f(x))^{g(x)}=1^{\infty}$$

Then :

$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(f(x))^{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}e^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$$

So :

$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{n^{4}}{n^{3}}}}{e^{\frac{(n+1)^{4}}{(n+1)^{3}}}}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{e^{n}}{e^{n+1}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{e}$$

Is my approach wrong ?

is this called partial limit calculation ?

Comment: This may work in this case but generally I would suggest an analysis of the behaviour of the numerator and denominator using Taylor's theorem for example. In this case $$\left(1+\frac1{n^3}\right)^{n^4}=e^n+o\left(\frac{e^n}n\right)$$So the ratio provided is effectively $(1+o(1/n))/(e+o(1/n))\to1/e$ as you have deduced.

Comment: @peterForeman can you test if my approach correct ?

Comment: Your approach has a flaw. The rule can be applied for expressions of type $f^g$. You can't apply it on numerator / denominator of a ratio and then divide. In calculus don't assume more than what is explicitly stated in theorems.

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

Use the inequality
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e < \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$
so
$$e^{\frac{1}{n+1}}< \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)< e^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
We get lower and upper bounds:
$$e^{\frac{n^4}{n^3+1}}< \left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}< e^n $$
$$e^{\frac{(n+1)^4}{(n+1)^3 +1}}< \left(1 + \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4} < e^{n+1}$$

Conclude:
$$e^{\frac{n^4}{n^3+1}}/e^{n+1}< \ldots < e^n/e^{\frac{(n+1)^4}{(n+1)^3 +1}}$$
so the limit is $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: That’s clever. $(+1)$

Comment: This is the best use of Squeeze I have seen so far on MSE. +1 A direct calculation like in my answer is tedious and error prone.

Comment: @orangeskid thank you sir 

Answer (score 3):

Your approach leads to the right answer, but there may be some questionable moves there. Me, I would apply $\ln$ to the expression and use

$$\tag 1 \ln (1+u) = u +O(u^2)$$

as $u\to 0.$ Thus in our problem we would get

$$n^4\ln(1+1/n^3) - (n+1)^4 \ln (1 +1/(n+1)^3).$$

Apply $(1)$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks sir but I don't understand why my approach wrong ?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you wrote $$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(f(x))^{g(x)}=1^{\infty}$$ I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: can you explain more

Answer (score 3):

Let's note that exponent $(n+1)^4$ in the denominator can be written as $$n^4+4n^3+\dots$$ and hence the denominator can be written as a product of a finite number of factors the first of which is $(1+(n+1)^{-3})^{n^4}$, the second of which is $(1+(n+1)^{-3})^{4n^3}$  and the remaining factors tend to $1$ (justify this yourself). The second factor tends to $e^{4}$. Thus the desired limit is equal to the limit of expression $$e^{-4}\left(\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{n^3}}{1+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^3}}\right)^{n^4}$$ which can be further rewritten as $$ e^{-4}\left(1+\frac{3n^2+3n+1}{n^3(1+(n+1)^3)}\right)^{n^4}$$ and then you can apply your formula to get the limit as $$e^{-4}\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} n^4\cdot\frac{3n^2+3n+1}{n^3((n+1)^3+1)}\right)=\frac{1}{e}$$

---

Expanding on my comment to your question, let's note that if your rule gave finite results for both numerator and denominator (including non-zero denominator) it would have been fine. But here it leads to the conclusion that both numerator and denominator tend to $\infty$. The rule says that if $f(x) \to 1$ and $g(x) \to\infty $ and further $\exp(g(x) (f(x) - 1))$ tends to a limit or to $\infty $ then so does $\{f(x) \} ^{g(x)} $. *It does not mean that under these circumstances you can replace the expression $f^g$ by $\exp(g(x)(f(x)-1))$*.

---

**Note**: The previous version of this answer used unnecessary manipulation which was tedious. Simplicity eludes us in surprising ways.

Comment: thanks sir !......+1

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you would like to get more than the limit itself, starting with
$$a_n=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}$$ take logarithms
$$\log(a_n)=n^4\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)-(n+1)^4\log\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)$$ Use twice the expansion
$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ and expand to get
$$\log(a_n)=-1-\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{3}{2n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ and continue with Taylor series
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=e\left(1-\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{3}{2n^4}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached. Moreover, this gives a shortcut estimation of $a_n$.

Suppose that, using your pocket calculator, you compute $a_3$. You should get
$a_3=0.3594$ while the above truncated expansion gives $\frac{53}{54 e}=0.3611$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Aonther method by Lagrange's MVT. Let 
$f(x)=x^4\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$,then
$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}
=e^{f(n)-f(n+1)}.$$
By Lagrange's MVT, there exists $\xi_n\in(n,n+1)$ such that
$$f(n+1)-f(n)=f'(\xi_n).$$
An elementary computation gives that
$$f'(x)=4x^3\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)-\frac{3x^3}{x^3+1},$$
and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=4-3=1.$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-f'(\xi_n)}=\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{-f'(x)}=\frac{1}{e}.$$

Comment: Very nice way!...+1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't shown how exactly you're using the lemma / theorem you referenced (for limits of the form $1^{\infty}$). The given limit is not $1^{\infty}$. It's actually $\infty/\infty$. So one explanation is that you're assuming
$$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}
=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}
$$
Now each of the limits (in the numerator and denominator) is $1^{\infty}$ and you could possibly apply the lemma. Except the above manipulation is wrong since both limits are $\infty$. What we could do instead is claim that
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}\sim e^n\,\,(n\to\infty)\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}\sim e^{n+1}\,\,(n\to\infty) $$
Such a claim requires justification of course. For example, by considering the series expansions of the expressions.

Comment: We can use this si @bjorn93 ? $\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}\sim e^n\,\,(n\to\infty)\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}\sim e^{n+1}\,\,(n\to\infty) $

Comment: @EllenEllen I don't understand your question. The $\sim$ stands for asymptotic equivalence. $f(x)\sim g(x)\,(x\to c)$ means that the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ is $1$ as $x\to c$. If you're not familiar with that concept, you have to consider other solutions.

Comment: Sir I mean that ; I can written $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}\frac{e^{n}}{e^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{e}$ ?? Is correct solution now ?

Comment: @EllenEllen This is true. The question is how you justify it. Based on what you wrote, I don't see a clear justification.

Comment: I use $\ln (1+x)~_{infty} x $ so $\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3})^{n^4}\right)=e^{n^{4}\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)}~e^{n}$ ? Correct ??

Comment: @EllenEllen Ok, after that what do you do? You really should add this to the body of your post instead of the comments.

Comment: @EllenEllen $f(x)^{g(x)}\sim e^{g(x)(f(x)-1)}$ is in general not true. In this case, it happens to be true. That's why we need more justification.

Comment: So , how ? We justified

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^4}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^4}}=\frac{\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^3}\right)^n}{\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)}}$$
$$=\frac{\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{n^3}\right)^n}{\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^3}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)^{(n+1)^3}}$$

Comment: How does this help? I don't see it as significantly different from the argument used in question.